# Activity to be closed from that activity itself in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I have 2 Activities, say activity A and activity B. I have to call activity B from the activity A. Now that is done by using Intent. There is some code in the activity A that must be executed after activity B ends. How can that be done?

I use the following code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

How can i accomplish that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage \`startActivityForResult\` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Comment: Heyy there, I have an error in the "Intent data" parameter of the onActivityResult function. How can that be solved ?

Answer (score 0):

According to Android Docs: "Starting another activity doesn't have to be one-way. You can also start another activity and receive a result back. To receive a result, call startActivityForResult() (instead of startActivity())."

[Activity For Result Doc](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android) you have a question about Activity For Result where you will find an example.

Comment: Hi , before answering, take a look that some one else took a time to answer this in the comment section, thanks

Comment: Heyy there, I have an error in the "Intent data" parameter of the onActivityResult function. How can tat be solved ?